# How can I stop cloud recording with Agora SDK?

Tags: agora.io, agora-cloud-recording

I am using Agora and have added cloud recording to my app. How do I stop the cloud recording?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the stop method to leave the channel and stop recording.

Agora Cloud Recording automatically stops recording and leaves the channel when there is no user in the recording channel after a time period (30 seconds by default). You can set this timeout interval by the maxIdleTime parameter when you start the recording.